# (Non Root)How to disable notification bar for all installed applications on android 5.1 and above?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I am creating a parental control application and i want to disable notification bar. I managed to disable notification bar for my application but how do i disable notification bar when i launch other installed application for example, default browser, contacts, calculator etc from my application?

Comment: look into switching on the immersive mode for the system. That removes the toolbar and disables back button.

Comment: Android 5.0 has a built-in kiosk mode. Use that.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Is there any link or reference that i can look into it?

Comment: Thanks geek90. I managed to disable the notification and navigation bar but do you have any idea how can i do the same thing for other installed app as well?